# get instagram user id using php foreach in wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, foreach

I created wordpress shortcode to get user ID by search,

I using foreach() but result not working!

I want foreach because i will make shortocde to get latest instagram images,

Resource:

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_retrieve_body

This is my code:

```
function insta_id($atts, $content = null){ 
    $my_access_token = "MY ACCESS TOKEN IS HERE";
    $get_id = wp_remote_get("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=youtube&access_token=$my_access_token&count=2");
    $retrieve_id = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $get_id );
    $result = json_decode($retrieve_id, true); 

    foreach ( $result as $user_id ) { // loop start
        print_r($user_id); // this working but display all array
        echo $user_id->id; // not working!
    } 

}
add_shortcode("insta_id", "insta_id");
```

`print_r($user_id);`  display this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => youtube [bio] => Behind the scenes with stars from your favorite YouTube channels. [website] => [profile_picture] => http://photos-b.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xaf1/10691785_700124036737985_752862120_a.jpg [full_name] => [id] => 1337343 ) [1] => Array ( [username] => youtubewtfff [bio] => ғυnniest moments on yoυтυвe  Kik: Youtubewtf Email : tysroark@hotmail.com Want a shoutout? Tag #Youtubewtf [website] => [profile_picture] => http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_489772119_75sq_1391400797.jpg [full_name] =>
```

Comment: I don't think `$user_id` is an object...

Comment: Look to print_r($user_id); message
I edited my post.

Comment: What if you `print_r($result)`, before the `foreach()`?

Comment: so its should be `$user_id['id']`

Answer (score 0):

You may be retrieving the wrong key from the response. Double check the instagram User ID with https://www.thekeygram.com/find-instagram-user-id/

It should be: `$user_id['id']`